# Message: Undefined index: pertanyaan_1

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got this function :

```
public function populateAtribut() 
    {
        $this->db->query("TRUNCATE atribut");
        $this->db->query("insert into `atribut` values
                    ('', 'Total', 'Total')
                    ");
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_1');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_2');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_3');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_4');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_5');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_6');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_7');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_8');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_9');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_10');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_11');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_12');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_13');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_14');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_15');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_16');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_17');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_18');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_19');
        $this->insertAtribut('pertanyaan_20');
    }
```

and i got function `insertAtribut` like this :

```
public function insertAtribut($atribut) {
        $sqlAtribut = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct `$atribut` FROM data_kepribadian ORDER by `$atribut`");
        while ($rowAtribut = $sqlAtribut->result_array()) {!
            $this->db->query("insert into `atribut` values
                        ('', '$atribut', '$rowAtribut[$atribut]')");
        }
    }
```

but i got error:

> Message: Undefined index: pertanyaan_1

and the program insert a data without stop to database.

How do i fix this?

Comment: You are getting this error because the index `pertanyaan_1` doesn't exist in the database table `data_kepribadian` at this point here `$rowAtribut[$atribut]`.

Comment: In your function insertAtribut, you take for granted that the value of $atribut is valid and contained in the table data_kepribadian.  What happens if it is not?  Validate the data in the table.  And make your function more robust by handling error scenarios.

Comment: @Alex in tabel data_kepribadian i have field pertanyaan_1.

Comment: @Nic3500 can you give me an example?

Comment: You obviously aren't getting that index from the database. `print_r($sqlAtribut->result_array())` after the query before the loop and post results.

Comment: @Alex this is the result Array ( [0] => Array ( [pertanyaan_1] => Adaptable ) [1] => Array ( [pertanyaan_1] => Adventurous ) [2] => Array ( [pertanyaan_1] => Analytical ) [3] => Array ( [pertanyaan_1] => Animated ) )

Comment: @Alex that's the result if i use print_r($sqlAtribut->result_array())

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is conditional:

```
while (condition is true) {
    code to be executed;
}
```

you have no condition so it just goes in a continuous loop. You need a foreach loop:

```
public function insertAtribut($atribut) {
    $sqlAtribut = $this->db->query("SELECT distinct `$atribut` FROM data_kepribadian ORDER by `$atribut`");
    if ($sqlAtribut->num_rows() > 0) {
        $rowAtribut = $sqlAtribut->result_array();
        foreach ($rowAtribut as $row) {
            $this->db->query("insert into `atribut` values ('', '$atribut', '$row[$atribut]')");
        }
    }
}
```

It also helps to check `num_rows` otherwise the foreach loop will fail if `$sqlAtribut` yields no results.

---

You can also clean up your queries and use query builder (but test this after testing above code to see if the logic works):

```
public function insertAtribut($atribut) {
    $q = $this->db->distinct()->select($atribut)->get('data_kepribadian');
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $rows = $q->result_array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $this->db->insert('atribut', array($atribut => $row[$atribut]));
        }
    }
}
```